# similarity between these two number series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have two number series:

$$4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\dots$$

and

$$30,60,105,168,252,360,495,660\dots$$

please could you help me to understand how these two series are related.
i.e. how can I obtain one if the other is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It we let the first sequence be denoted by $a_n$ and second sequence be denoted by $b_n$ then it looks like that $b_n = \frac{a_n^3-a_n}{2}$ but without further information i am not sure.

Comment: please ask more information if required.

Comment: What i meant is , without any other information about the 2 sequences you cant say for sure what relation hold true.

Comment: please can you tell me significance of this formula, is it related to any other theory?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A027480

Answer (score 1):

$$b_i = \frac{(a_i-1)a_i(a_i+1)}{2}$$ Oops, Ahmad had the answer before me.

Comment: please add more information about this formula, is it well know? how it is related to any other theory?

Comment: how you arrive at this formula ? i just said its at most a 7Degree polynomial and worked my way from there , did you do the same ?

Comment: @Ahmad To be honest, I did the search [30,60,105,168,252,360,495,660](https://oeis.org/search?q=30%2C60%2C105%2C168%2C252%2C360%2C495%2C660&language=english&go=Search) on OEIS. They have the sequence twice, but it became clear to me that it is what you get from multiplying three consecutive integers and dividing by two.

Answer (score 1):

If we denote the two series $a$ = first series and $b$ = second series, where terms are $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Let's check some ratios: $\frac{b_1}{a_1} = 7.5, \frac{b_2}{a_2} = 12, \frac{b_3}{a_3} = 17.5, \frac{b_4}{a_4} = 24, \frac{b_5}{a_5} = 31.5$

So let's say the series of differences between consecutive ratios are $d$, so: $d_1 = 4.5, d_2 = 5.5, d_3 = 6.5, d_4 = 7.5$. The pattern is that the differences increment by $1$ each time.

So if we want to get $a$ from $b$ and vice versa, we need to use this pattern to find a specific ratio. If we derive out a quadratic sequence with first term $7.5$, first difference $4.5$ and constant difference between differences $1$; the $nth$ ratio is $\frac{n^2 + 6n + 8}{2}$.

*I got this from a general sum function I derived for all quadratic sequences, if you want to I can post it here.*

So we know that the denominator for a ratio is $a_n$, which means $b_n$ must just be $a_n$ multiplied by the ratio:
$$b_n = a_n\frac{n^2 + 6n + 8}{2}$$
And similarly:

$$a_n = \frac{2b_n}{n^2 + 6n + 8}$$

***EDIT***: didn't notice that there were answers before me, I'll leave my answer here anyways.

Comment: d4 should be 7.5, please update it.

Comment: Yes sorry my bad!

Comment: I actually realized that it's possible to do it even easier now. Using a general sum function for all cubic sequences, we can just take the differences between terms in those series, thus yielding us a cubic sequence, then plug that into the formula and pretty much instantly get an answer.

Comment: you mean the formula given in other two answers, right?

Comment: Presumably, if the other two answers are correct then they will be the same. It will be the same as the solution I have as well; but it would be a lot easier to get to it, given that you have the sum function for a cubic series that is.

Comment: please explain it in your answer.

Comment: If you want to you can try yourself: $$S_3(n,s,d_1,p_1,c) = \frac{12sn + 6d_1n^2 - 6d_1n - 6p_1n^2 + 4p_1n - 3cn^3 - 3cn + 2p_1n^3}{12} + \frac{11cn^2 + cn^4}{24}$$

Where $s$ is the starting term of the series, $d_1$ is the first difference between the terms, $p_1$ is the first difference between the differences and $c$ is the constant difference between the differences of the differences.

With this formula you can get a closed form formula for the sum of any cubic series. The series HERE is differences of $b_n$ and $a_n$, i.e. $b_n - a_n = S_3(n,s,d_1,p_1,c) - S_3(n-1,s,d_1,p_1,c)$

Comment: thanks i will check it out.

Comment: Remember that that formula I posted above gets the SUM of the series, so to get the $nth$ term you just make the sum up to $n$, then remove the sum that is up to and including $n-1$. This will leave you with just $n$. So the series here looks like this: $30-4, 60-5, 105-6, 168-7, \ ...$

Here we have $s = 26$, $d_1 = 29$ (because second term $60-5$ minus first term $30-4$ is $29$), $p_1 = 15$ (similar reasoning but just one degree below $d_1$), and $c = 3$. Plug that in and take the sum up to $n$ terms minus the sum up to $n-1$ terms and you will get the difference $b_n - a_n$, then solve!